# Using Cordova, can I access files via links in JSON file?

Tags: android, json, cordova, file-access

I am making a web application that builds courses, and gets the data (modules, lessons, including texts, images, audio, video) from a JSON file.

People can exchange courses without using internet. A course is structured in a folder like this:

```
course.json
./audio
./video
./documents
./images
```

It can run fully offline, without server - as long as the data folders are within the application (that is, the html folder). But when the JSON is located elsewhere (say, in Downloads, Bluetooth or Documents), the JSON data itself will be shown, but not the data (images etc) it points to.

This is expected behavior, and can be solved by just moving the JSON and data folders to the right location. (which is for now acceptabe, but not in the long run)

But when I use Cordova to create an Android app, that won't be possible. And it looks like the file API doesn't have a solution for this.

So I would like to use the JSON file, wherever it may be located, as the root for getting the other data, or to be able to import a whole folder into the application.

Are there any options? Or should I go fully native?

UPDATE

It looks like it is impossible to get what I need (the path to the json file that is selected by a user, to re-create the links in the src attributes).

So the only possibility is to let users save their course files in a specific location (like Downloads or Documents).

As in the end I want to make courses downloadable as zip file, I go for the option to unzip that into the application - seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: Cordova File Plugin?

Comment: Not quite sure what your question actually is.  You can use the file API to move the JSON file to the desired location, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is : $cordovaFile, it has all required methods in order to manipulate files, like copying, moving and checking if files exists in a certain local path. Here is the doc : http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/.

PS. Don't go native, haha (personal opinion)

Comment: Ah, thanks master John! Looks like I ended up on the wrong pages, I got the impression that the file API was pretty much like the HTML5 File API, but this looks a lot better!